# JShell dollar variable name numbering

Tags: java, java-9, jshell

When I enter an expression in JShell (9.0.1) it comes back with:

```
$22 -> <value>
```

Where does the 22 come from and what's happened to $1 to $21? (They are undefined.)

I seem to vaguely remember (when I started with Java 9.0) that the variables started with $1, which made more sense. Now, with 9.0.1,they all start with $22. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are there, just do a

```
/list
```

to find the list of all. They are there because you seem to have already consumed 1 to 21[21 snippets/statements] until you reached the `$22 -> <value>` snippet.

Trying to `/reset` and then adding snippet should set you back :-

```
jshell> 0+1
$1 ==> 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I now realise the $1 to $21 are the printing methods implicitly created when I start jshell with the command line `jshell PRINTING`.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Indeed that's what I was assuming when I wrote *already consumed.*